# How to put pages number in one line in PagedList.Mvc?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am using PagedList.Mvc ver 3.18. Now information about pages is showing like this:

```
Page 1 of 3
    ← Previous
    1
    2
    3
    Next →
```

How to make it show in this way:

```
Page 1 of 3
← Previous 1 2 3 Next →
```

Index.cshtml

```
<div id="pager">
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
</div>
```

style.css

```
    #pager {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

How to put pages number in one line?

Answer (score 1):

Have you remembered to render the PagedList CSS file in the view?

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/PagedList.css")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("IndexMsgUser", new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }),
new PagedListRenderOptions()
{
           DisplayLinkToFirstPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
           DisplayLinkToPreviousPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
           DisplayLinkToLastPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
           DisplayLinkToNextPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
           MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 3, // number of pages in line
           DisplayEllipsesWhenNotShowingAllPageNumbers = false
})
```